# GLib usage with XCode

Tags: c, xcode, glib

I've been trying to use GLib in a project. I work with XCode. I downloaded Glib via Homebrew:

```
brew install glib
```

I then run

```
brew test glib
```

Which outputs

```
/usr/bin/clang -o test test.c -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.36.3/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.36.3/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.36.3/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lglib-2.0 -lintl -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
```

So, I copied all the -I arguments, and pasted them into XCode -> Project Settings -> Build Settings -> Other C Flags.

In a .c file inside my XCode project I have

```
    GList  *processList_p = NULL;      /* Pointer to the process list */
```

If I compile everything works, but then if I call a function from GLib, such as

```
//Create the new list element, append it to the list and return the pointer.
return g_list_append(processList, newProcess);
```

I get the error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_g_list_append", referenced from:
>         _CreateProcess in Scheduler.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I really have no idea what's going on, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see [Setting C++ compile flags in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346150/setting-c-compile-flags-in-xcode)

in short:
add result of
`pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
to Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags
NOT Build Settings -> Custom Compiler Flags -> Other C Flags

for some reason using
'pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0' directly does not work yielding:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Dash83 said, it's a linker issue. You need to let compiler to know the locations.

Outputs on my machine:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0

-I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include

$ pkg-config --libs glib-2.0

-L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Pass them to `clang`:

```
$ clang your_program.c -o your_program `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```

It compiles on my side.

Comment: To add to this using ` is very important over ' i found on mac.

Answer (score 0):

That is a linker problem my friend. I work with glib on vim on the console and came across your question looking for a quick start guide to use glib in xcode, so I can't really tell you how to fix it on xcode, but I can guarantee you that's a problem with the linker options/flags.

Comment: What I can tell you though, is that I use this command to pass the correct flags to my linker: `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`

Comment: Thanks, the answer for @raf did the trick, if you're still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. install pkg-config if not exists

   `brew install pkg-config`
2. list cflags

   `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
3. manual choose pkg if  not exists

   `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/pkgconfig/ pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`