# Setting C compile flags in xcode

Tags: ios, c, xcode, clang

I've been trying to compile some C files to use in XCode that uses Openssl as a dependency for encryption. When compiling with clang the code compiles fine. I read a few posts on here like [Setting C++ compile flags in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346150/setting-c-compile-flags-in-xcode) that says to put the flags under Other Linker Flags but I still couldn't get it to recognize it.

Here is the compiling command that works on the command line:

[image]

Flags in XCode:

[image]

The error in XCode:

[image]

Comment: setting compiler settings and header include paths under linker settings isn't going to work; that's not where you add user-defined header folders (i.e additional header directories). Open the schema editor for your target and search for "Header" (yes, there actually is a "search" facility to make it easier to find stuff).

Comment: Do I add it under "Header Search Paths"?

Comment: Yes, and **only** the include paths; not the warning settings, output target name, or any of the other stuff you have there. It should be just the added paths; no `-I` directives or anything like that; Xcode adds all of that when submitting to clang).

Comment: I've been trying to add it there for the last half hour but no luck. I feel like I'm close. Can you take a look and see what's off about it? http://prntscr.com/kfhyhp

Comment: For one, the **lib** folder doesn't belong there. Additional *library* search paths has its own place in Xcode. Second, *look at your errors*. Those are *link* errors, not compile errors. Which means it is a different problem than the one you came here with. Your original problem was where to tell Xcode about additional header search paths: done. Now your problem is where to tell Xcode about additional *library* search paths, And yes, there is another path setting you can configure for Xcode that does that too.

Comment: I've tried adding it in the Library Search Paths instead as well but it didn't help the link errors. Is this the place to put it? http://prntscr.com/kfi2x9

Comment: Figured out the solution. Will be posting it in a bit

Comment: I suspect it will be a combination of everything you've already done, and added to that, adding `-lcrypto` to your linker flags (where this all started).

Comment: Yup exactly. Thanks a bunch man. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution thanks to @WhozCraig

Add the include folder in "Header Search Paths" and library folder in "Library Search Paths"

[image]

Then put -lcrypto to link the files under "Other Link Flags"

[image]