# Changing clang to compile in C11 or higher?

Tags: c, terminal, clang

I'm following a tutorial on learning C. I'm currently using a Mac with clang 11.0.3. It is in C99 by default (I'm getting the error: warning: implicit declaration of function 'of' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration].)
I'm using xcode 11.5.

How do I update/change the default of clang to C11 or higher?

Comment: `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu11`

Comment: Here is a [page of flags](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html).

Comment: joek, Do you want ot change  things so calling the compiler without a flag results in C11 or is passing in a select flag good enough?

Comment: As Gilles notes, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  The choice of C standard is not the issue; the problem is in your code, and it'll still be illegal (and incorrect) under C11.  If `of` is really a function, it needs to be declared; it may also be a mistake.  If you could actually post the code in question, people could help you figure out which.

Comment: Yes I've realised 1) The eBook I copied and pasted the code from added hyphens at the line break, turning "sizeof" into "size-of". 2) The book uses %d, but replacing them with %lu has worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can look up the documentation with `man clang` on your system or [online on the Clang website](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#command-line-options) (https://clang.org → “Getting started” → “User's Manual” link on the left).

> clang supports the -std option, which changes what language mode clang uses. The supported modes for C are c89, gnu89, c99, gnu99, c11, gnu11, c17, gnu17, c2x, gnu2x, and various aliases for those modes. If no -std option is specified, clang defaults to gnu17 mode.

Note that since you're seeing C99 as the language version, your IDE is likely passing a `-std` option already. I don't know where to control compiler options in Xcode but [Setting C compile flags in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715807/setting-c-compile-flags-in-xcode) might help.

The Clang documentation is not always complete or clear. Many features of Clang mimic [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), and GCC often has better documentation. The section on [C dialect options in the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) has more information about `-std` and its values. You need to be careful because Clang doesn't always work exactly like GCC, but the GCC documentation is often helpful as long as you remember that it may not always apply to Clang.

None of this will help you anyway because switching from C99 to C11 wouldn't fix this particular error. Implicit function declarations are a deprecated feature in C89 which was made invalid in C99, and `of` is not a new keyword in C11, so either your code is bad-style C89 or more likely there's a typo and `of` should not be a function name.

Comment: Nice answer but I would put the last paragraph first.

Comment: @NateEldredge The last paragraph will help the original asker, and not many other people. The rest of my answer will help future visitors. I think that the expected number of future visitors is more than 1 (that's a major premise behind Stack Exchange), so I write for everyone, not just for the original asker.